# Does FTP control connection have binary or textual data inside?

Tags: networking, ftp, protocol, network-protocols

From [this post](http://www.coreftp.com/docs/web1/Ascii_vs_Binary_transfers.htm) we know that

> There are two common modes for transferring files via FTP, ascii and binary

It is about *media connection*. But also there is a *control connection*, which has some info like IP addresses and so on.
Does the info inside *control connection* have binary or textual format?

Comment: Have you researched the relevant RFCs which define the FTP protocol?

Comment: @user1686 I'm currently researching it but can't still figure out things.

Comment: Short answer: text

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTP control connection is text. It's mostly 4-character all-caps command mnemonics and occasional IP addresses (in dotted-decimal ASCII) and port numbers (in ASCII numerals). And of course path and file names in text.

Comment: It's not just that it's text – but it's also specifically defined to be NVT-ASCII text with CRLF line endings, so it's exactly the same as "ASCII" data transfer mode.